# Prove that squares split the plane into regions that have boundary equal to some Jordan curve.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, plane-curves, polygons

In Tao's proof of the Jordan curve theorem in the [appendix of his 246A Notes 3](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/math-246a-notes-3-cauchys-theorem-and-its-consequences/) he covers a simple closed curve $\gamma$ with squares of small sidelength and claims that "the boundaries of these squares divide the complex plane into a finite number of polygonal regions". I provide his illustration:
[image]
I want to make that rigorous as follows: for a collection of square curves $\gamma_{\square, 1}, \ldots, \gamma_{\square, n}$, the complement of the union of their images is an open set; then each connected component of this open set has boundary equal to a disjoint union of simple closed curves (consisting of pieces of the original $\gamma_{\square,i}$ of course).

I think this is true for say circles as well, but I am having a very hard time proving the claim in both the case for squares and circles. ***Caveat:*** there are probably some issues with simplicity of the curves, but we can perturb the squares/circles a bit so we can basically ignore that issue.

EDIT: seems like this question has pretty much already been asked before: [Jordan Curve Theorem, Professor Tao's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686151/jordan-curve-theorem-professor-taos-proof).

Comment: The boundaries of the squares are Piecewise Linear, and the proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem for the Piecewise Linear case should follow nearly immediately (via perturbation) from the proof of the smooth case, which is comparatively easy.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen note that I'm not proving the JCT (starting from a simple closed curve and proving the existence of the interior and exterior), but rather starting from an interior/exterior and asking whether or not the boundary is a simple closed curve.

Comment: To show the boundary of $A$ is PL is rather trivial, since it's a connected subset of the union of the boundaries of the shapes (each of which is PL). That the boundary is a disjoint union of closed curves is rather obvious as well (as long as the curves are in general position... a counterexample otherwise is $A = [0,1]^2 \cup [-1,0]^2$, which has closed but not disjoint curves as its boundary).

Comment: To make life easier we assume each shape is convex, and we may assume WLOG we are working with a connected union (since the boundary of disjoint sets is the union of the boundaries). Let $A = A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$, and choose a point $x \in \partial A_1 \setminus (\partial A_2 \cup \cdots \partial A_n)$. Move along $\partial A_1$ in the the counter-clockwise orientation $x$ at unit speed, and stop when we hit an intersection point. Since we are working in general position, we are at the point of intersection of $A_1$ with exactly one of the $A_i$.

Comment: Continuing along $\partial A_1$ would take us into the interior of $A_i$, and likewise traveling clockwise along $\partial A_i$ would take us into the interior of $A_1$. In either case we would leave the boundary, and since we know the boundary must be connected (being the boundary of a non-disjoint union of connected sets) we must have to travel counterclockwise along $\partial A_i$; do so at unit speed. Since we are working with PL curves of finite length, this process must terminate in finite time and hit every $A_j$.

Comment: The convexity assumption essentially says that we could scale up all the shapes and choose a tubular neighborhood around the boundary of the convex hull of $A$ such that movement around $\partial A$ stays within this tubular neighborhood; this guarantees we must return back to where we started, and also that the curve is simple.

Comment: There are some details to fill in there, but that should give one (probably not very efficient) route to solve the problem. Note in the above I meant for $A$ to be the union of your shapes, and you are really asking to show that the boundary of $A^c$ is a disjoint union of simple closed curves. This follows from what I wrote above since $\partial(A^c) = \partial A$ is a general topological fact.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen if you wouldn't mind, it would be easier to read in an answer format (not just comment). Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Why did you write 6 comments to avoid an official answer?

Comment: Tao writes "Actually, the boundary must consist of just one closed path, since otherwise the union of the squares $S$ would be disconnected." I would regard this as much too short to be a proper argument. In particular, his definition of the squares does not exclude that there is a point $p$  in the curve lying in exactly two squares having $p$ as common vertex. This point prevents the boundary from being a closed path. You can resolve this by adpating the definition, and then Tao's claim is correct and inituitvely clear, but how can we be sure that there are no other pitfalls?

Comment: @PaulFrost he does write that via perturbations we can make sure two distinct squares do not have colinear edges. But yes in general I found his argument very "sketchy". To be fair, these are just "Notes"